# SelectedNodeChange System.Web.UI.WebControls.treeview not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have derived a control from the above namespace to incorporate an object tag as this seems to be missing from the above.

Within my code, I populate my tree control and set the select item. However no events are fired...

```
<PulmanGroup:PulmanTreeControl ID="FileContentsTreeView" runat="server"                         EnableTheming="True" CssClass="AspNet-TreeView" display="block" right="400px" ImageSet="Simple" NodeIndent="30" ShowLines="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled" onselectednodechanged="FileContentsTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged" PopulateNodesFromClient="False"> <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" runat="server"/>
<LeafNodeStyle CssClass=".AspNet-TreeView-Leaf" runat="server"/><NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" runat="server"/> <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" CssClass="AspNet-TreeView-Parent" runat="server"/><RootNodeStyle CssClass="AspNet-TreeView-Root " runat="server"/><SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" VerticalPadding="0px" CssClass="SelectedStyle" Height="20px" runat="server" /></PulmanGroup:PulmanTreeControl>
```

I have tried to ensure postback using the "PopulateNodesFromClient" to false.
I have also pragmatically set the select action upon each node using the code below.

```
    protected void FileContentsTreeView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(File_Hash.type==0)
                    throw new Exception("Something's wrong");

                PulmanTreeNode rnode = new PulmanTreeNode();
                rnode.Text = File_Hash.text; //Sets the root......
                FileContentsTreeView.Nodes.Add(rnode);
                rnode.NavigateUrl = "";
                rnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
                foreach(BudgetObject bd in ((BudgetObjectContainer)File_Hash).BusinessObjects)
                {
                    PulmanTreeNode pnode = new PulmanTreeNode();
                    rnode.ChildNodes.Add(pnode);
                    pnode.Tag = bd;
                    pnode.Text = bd.text;
                    pnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
                    pnode.NavigateUrl = "";
                    if (bd.type ==2 || bd.type == 3 ) // Is a parent.
                        FileContentsRecursiveTreeView_Load(sender, e, pnode, ((BudgetObjectContainer)bd)); 

                }
                FileContentsTreeView.CollapseAll();
            }

        protected void FileContentsRecursiveTreeView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, TreeNode TreeContainer, BudgetObjectContainer boc)
        {
            foreach (BudgetObject bd in boc.BusinessObjects)
            {
                PulmanTreeNode pnode = new PulmanTreeNode();

                pnode.Expanded = false;
                pnode.Text = bd.text;
                pnode.Tag = bd;
                pnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
                pnode.NavigateUrl = "";
                TreeContainer.ChildNodes.Add(pnode);
                if (bd.type == 2 || bd.type == 3) // Is a parent.
                    FileContentsRecursiveTreeView_Load(sender, e, pnode, ((BudgetObjectContainer)bd));
            }
        }
protected void FileContentsTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PulmanTreeNode node = (PulmanTreeNode)FileContentsTreeView.SelectedNode;

            BudgetObject bo = (BudgetObject)node.Tag;

            StatusLabel.Text = bo.text + " " + node.Text;

            return;
        }
```

But, I can't seem to get the event to fire. My custom control uses the viewstate and is repopulated when I click an item, so I know postback and viewstate are occurring and I have ensured the navigateURL is empty but even with this line of code emitted, the event still does not fire...

Equally, I have also performed a test in which I am using a standard treeview and where the nodes are populated from the designer and no events are fired....

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
UPDATE

So, despite no events being fired upon the tree control a postback request is made. 
I debugged the code and found both the selected node is null and the value is an empty string. Despite this - the CSS still highlights the selected entry.... So something is happening but I have no idea what.

As requested - here is the CSS, the only part that does not work with it is the hide. However, this is cosmetic, the html seems fine.

The only two members my control inherit are:

```
  protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            object[] arrState = new object[2];
            arrState[1] = base.SaveViewState();
            //arrState[0] = this._data;
            arrState[0] = this.Tag;
            return arrState;
        }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object state)
    {
        object[] arrState = state as object[];

        //this._data = ((BudgetObject)arrState[0]);
        this.Tag = arrState[0];
        base.LoadViewState(arrState[1]);
    }
```

The generated html looks like:

```
<li class="AspNet-TreeView-Parent">
                                    <span class="AspNet-TreeView-Expand" onclick="ExpandCollapse__AspNetTreeView(this)">&nbsp;</span>
                                    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit')">
                                         Gross Profit</a>
                                    <ul class="AspNet-TreeView-Hide">
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ Retail')">
                                                 Retail</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ Dealer Installed Accessories')">
                                                 Dealer Installed Accessories</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ Delivery')">
                                                 Delivery</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ F&amp;&amp;I Commission')">
                                                 F&&I Commission</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ Finance Volume Bonus')">
                                                 Finance Volume Bonus</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ Retail Sales Bonus')">
                                                 Retail Sales Bonus</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ Other Income')">
                                                 Other Income</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-TreeView-Leaf">
                                            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$FileContentsTreeView','sRoot\\NEW RETAIL\\ Gross Profit\\ Total New Gross Profit')">
                                                 Total New Gross Profit</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
```

Comment: can you use the debugger of the browser?  maybe its console log window can give some insight (missing library, duplicated library, etc)

Comment: No missing libraries I'm afraid. I really don't get this. I have some css to highlight the selected node in the treeview. This works perfectly meaning an event has been fired and the selected node highlighted. But no code is called on that event...

Comment: can you post some (not all) of the HTML/CSS/JS ?  the C# is server side using a custom (PulmanGroup:PulmanTreeControl) library making things trickier

Comment: I discovered App_Browsers/CSSFriendlyAdapters.browser was causing the issue. 

This helper class overloaded the event handling itself, meaning my code was never called. Removing the treeview class from this list resolved the issue.